# How to make changes to the "navigate up" button in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint so forgive the simple question, but I would like to make changes to the "navigate up" button in SharePoint 2010.  I have access to the Site Settings and the Look and Feel Section, but If I want to change the text of the links, or add a new link, how do I do this?  There should not be any code changes, as I assume this can be done through SharePoint out of the box.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was Portal Connection I needed to go to!